# How to turn off hover with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a keyframe animation that lasts 6 seconds. What I want is : Every time I click on '.box', wait animation end (6 seconds),

```
$('.box').click(function() {
        $('.content').addClass("my-animation"); // this animation last 6 seconds
    });
```

then activate this hover fonction :

```
 $('.content').hover(function() {
// ... specific animation
}, function() {
// ...
});
```

In other words I want to "turn off" the hover function **only when** #content is animated, because if I hover on my content while "my-animation" is running, it cancels.

EDIT html :

```
<p class="box">see</p>
<p class="content faconC button-p"> title </p>
```

Comment: Can I have HTML please?

Comment: set a flag. if flag is true, exit the hover handler early. Once the animation is done, set flag to false. $$. however, this sounds like an over-use of animations.

Comment: Cant you just `hasClass` in the hover function and check if the element has the class of animation?

Comment: @Varun the element would presumably still have that class >6 seconds.

Comment: @Varun You say detect if element hasclass 'my-animation'... then hover = false or something like that ?

Comment: @JbDel Yes that will work if the `my-animation` class is removed after the animation completes!
In that case you can just have an if condition on the hover function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add a variable to prevent the hover.  No need for unbinding/rebinding..

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
      var isAnimating = false;

      $('.box').on('click', function() {
        isAnimating = true;
        
        $('.content').addClass("my-animation"); // this animation last 6 seconds
        setTimeout(() => { isAnimating = false; }, 6000);
      });

      $('.content').hover(function()  {
        if (isAnimating) return;
        $(this).addClass('border-green');
      }, function() {
        if (isAnimating) return;
        // do something else...
        $(this).removeClass('border-green');
      });
    });
```

```css
.box, .content{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  transition-duration: 6s;
  transition-property: transform;
}
.content { border-color: blue; }

.my-animation{
  transform:rotate(360deg);
}

.border-green { border-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="box">Box</p>
<p class="content">Title</p>
```

If you have multiple `.box` on the screen let me know, I'll update the answer to work with multiple `.box` and `.content` objects.

Comment: interesting solution. I have two .box and multiple .content objetcs. Its working well If the user hover quickly on it. but if user hover later, hover animation appears after 6 seconds, not instantly.

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense.  The animation cannot happen automatically after 6 seconds.  None of my code executes an animation after 6 seconds.

Comment: Effectively, you are right, your code makes the hover animation works properly. But when I first hover on it, animation happen after 6 seconds. Its fine only after this first hover...

Comment: Added working example.  Right away you can hover content, which turns the border green.  If you click the red box, title rotates but CANNOT turn green until the animation is finished.  After the animation is finished, you can hover again and change the color to green.  This does exactly what you stated: *I want to "turn off" the hover function only when #content is animated,*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method to remove all handlers attached to hover event when animation start:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
     // detach hover handler
     $('.content').off('hover', handler);

     // start animation
     $('.content').addClass("my-animation");

     // reattach handler after 6s
     setTimeout(function() {
         $content.on('hover', handler);
     }, 6000);
});

$content.on('hover', handler);

function handler(e) {

    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
        // ... Specific animation
    } else { // mouseleave
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: working pretty well If the user hover quickly on it. but if user hover later... hover animation will start after 6 seconds and its not what I want.

Comment: I tried it, my animation is running but now, hover animation don't work. It works like very fast if I hover very fast on content after I click, then its not working anymore. (my-animation is still working in that case).